# Adding object to array using controllers model

Tags: javascript, arrays, ember.js

Hello i'm trying to add an object to an array using ember. The friends controller model returns an array of objects (App.friends).

From the friends/new template I get a users firstName,lastName and about them.

Once I've gotten that the user clicks create and the information is added to App.friends through using the needs feature of ember to access App.friends from inside the FriendsNewController.

For some reason im getting the following error when i click create,

Uncaught TypeError: desc.get is not a function

```
App.FriendsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return App.friends;
    }
});


App.FriendsNewController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    needs: "friends",
    isInvalid: true,

    validForm: function(){

        if(this.get('lastName') && this.get('firstName')){
            this.set("isInvalid", false);
        } else {
            this.set("isInvalid", true);
        }

    }.observes('firstName','lastName'),

    actions: {
        create: function(){
            var newFriend = Ember.copy(this.content);
                this.get('controllers.friends.model').addObject(newFriend);
            this.transitionToRoute('friends');
        }
    }
});

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="friends/new">
    <label>First Name</label>
    {{input value=firstName}}<br />

    <label>Last Name</label>
    {{input value=lastName}}<br />

    <label>About</label>
    {{textarea value=about}}<br />

    <button {{action "create"}} {{bind-attr disabled=isInvalid}}>Create</button>

  </script>

      App.friends = [
    {id: 1, firstName: "John", lastName: "Joe", about: "Funny"},
    {id: 2, firstName: "Mary", lastName: "Joey", about: "Smart"},
    {id: 3, firstName: "Henry", lastName: "Jim", about: "Kind"}
];
```

Im extremely new to Ember, so feel free to push me in the right direction. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are on the right track.

In the following line you are trying to add an object to a controller:

```
this.get('controllers.friends').addObject(newFriend);
```

But it should be added to an array:

```
this.get('controllers.friends.model').addObject(newFriend);
```

What is `App.friends`? For `addObject` to work it should be an Ember Array (not a plain array, i.e. `[1,2]` vs `Ember.A([1,2])`)

Comment: I changed it too .model, i did try that before but it didn't fix the issue, You talk about Ember arrays, how do i define one? i added to the code where i define the array

Comment: Can you show me the code where you define the array?

Comment: Ok :) Try the following: `App.friends = Ember.A([
    {id: 1, firstName: "John", lastName: "Joe", about: "Funny"},
    {id: 2, firstName: "Mary", lastName: "Joey", about: "Smart"},
    {id: 3, firstName: "Henry", lastName: "Jim", about: "Kind"}
])`

Comment: And let me know. If it doesn't work I'll set up a sample app and see what's going on!

Comment: I swapped where i got my ember.js files from, somehow that fixed the issue, although its appending a seemingly empty object, which is a separate issue

Comment: `var newFriend = Ember.copy(this.model)` (instead of `this.content`)?

Comment: (And if this is beyond a test app, it would be a good idea to use Ember CLI)